# Changing the name of app containers in the iCloud Drive on OS X?

Tags: macos, finder, icloud

I am using the iCloud Drive, and sometimes the name of an app folder is too clumsy and too long to own a place on the Finder sidebar. Per the previous attempts by others, the Finder sidebar uses only the original folder name, but ignore the alias name for all its items. So using alias isn't a viable approach to workaround the name of app containers.

As known from the iCloud Programming Guide, the name of the app containers is actually specified by a key in the app-provided plist. The file hierarchy of the iCloud Drive does prove this, but the plist doesn't seem storing together with the Documents folder for each app. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some searches in the Library folder, the plists and the app icons of the app containers are located in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/containers/
```

Change the BRContainerName property in the plist of an app container, and restart the Mac. The iCloud Drive in the Finder will then display the changed name. As shown in the following screenshot, the app folder "Documents" was supposed to have a longer name "Documents by Readdle".

[image: iCloud Drive in Finder]

Without locking the plist, the name still hasn't been reverted after a restart. So it is still unknown in what circumstance the plist will be reverted back to the original version by the *bird* daemon. But given the fact that the plist specifies the corresponding app version, it will probably be reverted on an version update to the container-owner app.

P.S. Document Picker on iOS and the iCloud Drive web app are not affected by this.